# react-hot-loader and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npm-install, react-hot-loader

I am new in stackoverflow and I am junior in React
I have a question
I installed webpack V5 and then I try to install react-hot-loader.
This is webpack.config.js

`

```
const path = require ("path");
const webpack = require ("webpack");

module.exports = {
    module :{
        entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
             dependency: { not: ['url'] },
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'url-loader',
                  options: {
                    limit: 8192,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve :{extensions : ["*" , ".js" , ".jsx"]},
    devServer: {
        // contentBase
        static : {
          directory : path.join(__dirname, "public/")
        },
        port: 3000,
        // publicPath
        devMiddleware:{
           publicPath: "https://localhost:3000/dist/",
        }
        
      },
};
```

`

I want to install React-hot-loader but it does`nt install and I have error

Comment: As a junior, I would suggest you use a framework like Create React App (https://create-react-app.dev/) or Next.js (https://nextjs.org/) so you can concentrate on learning React rather than the build framework.
Unless, of course, your intention is to learn about webpack rather than React.

Comment: I worked with Create React App , but I try to learning webpack , so... thank you!

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Can you provide details of the error you're seeing, and when you see it?